About Design Pattern - Avoid excessive looping
I am relatively new to the Salesforce world, working as a developer at a company that provides Salesforce consulting.
Well, I usually gain experience by looking at what is done in other projects and applying it to the ones I develop. Today, this is my (summarized) call structure:
Trigger
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert , before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
        SObjectTriggerHandler.run(new  OpportunityBO());
}

Handler
public with sharing class OpportunityBO extends SObjectTriggerHandler{
    
    private static Integer instanceCount = 0;

    private List<Opportunity> opportunities;
    private List<Opportunity> oldOpportunities;
    private Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunitiesMap;
    private Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunitiesOldMap;
    private Integer instanceIndex;
 
    Override
    protected String getInstanceIdentifier(){
        return '>>> Opportunity Trigger nº ' + instanceIndex + ':';
    }

    public OpportunityBO(){
        super();
        this.opportunities = super.newList;
        this.oldOpportunities = super.oldList;
        this.opportunitiesMap = (Map<Id, Opportunity>) super.newMap;
        this.opportunitiesOldMap = (Map<Id, Opportunity>) super.oldMap;
        instanceIndex = instanceCount++;
    }
    
    Override
    protected void onBeforeInsert(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + ' onBeforeInsert()');
        new OpportunityService(this.opportunities,this.opportunitiesMap).method1().method2().method3();
    }
    
    Override 
    protected void onAfterInsert(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + ' onAfterInsert()');
        new OpportunityService(this.opportunities,this.opportunitiesMap).method4();
    }
    
    Override
    protected void onBeforeUpdate(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + ' onBeforeUpdate()');
        new OpportunityService(this.opportunities,this.opportunitiesMap).method1().method3();
    }
    
    Override
    protected void onAfterUpdate(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + ' onAfterUpdate()');
        new OpportunityService(this.opportunities,this.opportunitiesMap).method4();
    }

    Override
    protected void onBeforeDelete(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + ' onBeforeDelete()');
        new OpportunityService(this.opportunities,this.opportunitiesMap).method5();
    }

    Override
    protected void onAfterDelete(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + 'onAfterDelete()');
        new OpportunityService(this.opportunities,this.opportunitiesMap).method6();
    }
    
    Override
    protected void onAfterUndelete(){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, getInstanceIdentifier() + 'onAfterUndelete()');
    }
}

Service
public with sharing class OpportunityService {
    List<Opportunity> opportunities;
    Map<Id,Opportunity> opportunitiesMap;
    public OpportunityService(List<Opportunity> opps, Map<Id,Opportunity> oppsMap) {
        opportunities = opps;
        opportunitiesMap = oppsMap;
    }

    public OpportunityService method1(){
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            //LOGIC
        }
        return this;
    }

    public OpportunityService method2(){
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            //LOGIC
        }
        return this;
    }

    public OpportunityService method3(){
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            //LOGIC
        }
        return this;
    }

    public OpportunityService method4(){
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            //LOGIC
        }
        return this;
    }

    public OpportunityService method5(){
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            //LOGIC
        }
        return this;
    }

    public OpportunityService method6(){
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            //LOGIC
        }
        return this;
    }

}

I think it is organized; however, as the number of methods in the service increases, I notice that I end up looping through the same records. Is there a design pattern that can avoid this? Which design pattern do you use? Could you give me a simple example?

The trigger events (before insert, after insert, ....) are separate transactions

@identigral The thing you linked to doesn't say that at all... before/after events (i.e. before update + after update) are part of the same transaction, as are the re-run after non-fast-record-update flows with field updates, and any other triggers that get run as a result of running code.

We didn't mean Apex transaction but fair point, separate events would be a better term.

if looking at loops bothers you -- look at this github package https://github.com/ipavlic/apex-fp

tl;dr:
Don't worry so much about performance until you know it's an issue (and can measure it).
Just focus on making it easy to read and test, and keeping things like queries and DML outside of all loops.
longer version
While there is overhead associated with looping, being limited to 10k DML rows in any given transaction makes that not so much of an issue.

A bare loop, iterating 10k times takes ~5 cpu time units
A bare loop over 10k SObjects takes ~25 cpu time units (seems to be the same even when taking into consideration that triggers are chunked into groups of 200)
A while loop using an iterator from a list of 10k SObjects takes ~80 cpu time units
A soql-for-loop (for(Account acct : [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10000])) takes ~300 cpu time units

The governor limit is 39,000 cpu time units (for synchronous transactions).
The performance of the iterator approach kinda surprised me. I had thought that would've been the fastest. Guess I need to go back and read a certain blog post again.
Aside from the SOQL for loop, you'd need to run about 50 loops over 10k records to hit 4,000 cpu units (a bit over 10% of the limit) in the worst case. The logic being executed inside the loop is going to dwarf that.
Here's the simple benchmark anon apex I whipped up to test
Integer rows = 10000;
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10000];//new List<Account>();
List<Account> accounts2 = new List<Account>();
List<List<Account>> acctsList = new List<List<Account>>{new List<Account>()};
for(Integer i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    accounts2.add(new Account());

    if(Math.mod(i, 200) == 0) {
        acctsList.add(0, new List<Account>());
    }

    acctsList[0].add(new Account(Name = 'acct' + i));
}

Long cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, cpu4, cpu5, cpu6, cpu7, cpu8;

cpu1 = Datetime.now().getTime();
for(Account acct : accounts) {

}
cpu2 = Datetime.now().getTime();

// Simulating trigger chunks of 200 records each
Long total = 0;
for(List<Account> acctList : acctsList) {
    cpu3 = Datetime.now().getTime();
    for(Account acct : acctList) {
        // uncomment to see that logic inside of loops is what takes time
        //Account a2 = new Account(name = acct.Name);
    }
    cpu4 = Datetime.now().getTime();
    system.debug('2:' + (cpu4-cpu3));
    total += cpu4 - cpu3;
}

cpu5 = Datetime.now().getTime();
Iterator<Account> it = accounts.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
}
cpu6 = Datetime.now().getTime();

cpu7 = Datetime.now().getTime();
for(Account acct : [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10000]) {

}
cpu8 = Datetime.now().getTime();

system.debug('1:' + (cpu2-cpu1));
system.debug('2:' + (total));
system.debug('3:' + (cpu6-cpu5));
system.debug('4:' + (cpu8-cpu7));
system.debug(Limits.getLimitCPUTime());


What's a CPU time unit? How do you arrive at 39,000 time units? Also, the inline query happens to be slower because of the internal use of queryMore to chunk the query into batches of 200. Takes more CPU time, but there are cool things you can do with it.

@sfdcfox I had it in my head that the documentation didn't always specify that was milliseconds, and the 39k figure is what I see for the limits usage statements in debug logs (also through Limits.getLimitCpuTime()). Maybe that 39k figure is specific to my org/edition? At any rate, that disconnect between documentation and what I see has confused me for some time (and part of why I wasn't sure if the CPU limit was measured in ms or some other unit).

A typical trigger framework (example) abstracts the trigger operation into three parts: bulkBefore(), action(record), and bulkAfter(). Note that this doesn't "save" any loops during execution, but it will reduce the number of loops you need to write, making it easier to maintain overall. You could make this even more efficient by implementing various handlers as interfaces, allowing you to make a dynamic trigger framework that can be controlled by custom metadata or other configuration options. The very nature of triggers (that is, being properly bulkified) means that every single trigger should loop over records. It's difficult to avoid "excessive" looping. That said, "generics", when (or if) they come out, will make it easier to avoid writing an excessive amount of loops.
